# json output is not in sorting order

Tags: java, web-services, rest, netbeans

I have created web service in JAVA Netbeans and called MySQL data through rest web service.

Edited code:

For loop shows all areas in sorting order then why as json output all data are not displayed in ascending order???

my method is as follows :

```
    @GET
@Path("/ShowAreasDup")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<EntityAreas> ShowAreasDup(){

    ArrayList<EntityAreas> listSort;

    try{           
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASSWORD);
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Areas ORDER BY AreaName";
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);
    // iterate through the java resultset
    while (resultset.next())
    {
        int id = resultset.getInt("AreaID");
        String restroName = resultset.getString("AreaName");

        EntityAreas anames=new EntityAreas();
        anames.setAreaid(id);
        anames.setAreaname(restroName);
        ShowentityAreas.put(id, anames);      
    }       
    statement.close();            
    }
    catch(HeadlessException | SQLException |ClassNotFoundException ee)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ee);
    }       

    listSort=new ArrayList<EntityAreas>(ShowentityAreas.values());
    Collections.sort(listSort,new Comparator<EntityAreas>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(EntityAreas o1, EntityAreas o2) {
            return o1.getAreaname().compareTo(o2.getAreaname());
        }

    });

    for(EntityAreas entityarea:listSort){
        System.out.println(entityarea);
    }

    return listSort;
}
```

thank you in advance for help

Edit :
Above code is works perfectly for me 
thanks to all for giving me a direction to the answser :)

Comment: make sure you are sorting on the correct field; looking at the code it seems you are trying to sort on AreaName in ascending order

Comment: yes, there are only 2 fields AreaID and AreaName in Areas Table

Comment: my code is perfectly run and displays data in json form @Masud but only i want is to display all in ascending order

Comment: Why your method is returning a type `ArrayList<? extends Object>`?! Try to declare your list of result as `List<Areas> listkeys`, instead of using the type w/out Generics.

Comment: I don't know more about Generics , i try this on the basis of some tutorials available on internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your code, there could be some hypothesis. The most probable is that `ShowAreas` stores the information in an non ordered data structure (for example an `HashMap`).

If you want to maintain your values in order , you have to use some additional data structure. For example, you can use a `TreeSet` for the values.

Another solution could be to sort the values immediatly before returning them ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))),

```
// Get the elements
List<Areas> areas = new ArrayList<Areas>(ShowAreas.values());
// Sort them
Collections.sort(areas);
// Return them
return areas;
```

**Pay attention**: if you want to use this method, the class `Areas` must implement `Comparable`.

A last advise: don't put the code that interacts with the database in the class that has the responsibility to receive external REST calls. You violates the *single responsibility principle* and your application will become unmaintainable very quickly. Try to use a structure *Controller* - *Service* - *Repository*.

Comment: second solution gives error, and I am trying to implement TreeSet solution, thank you

Comment: I had edited my answer: I've wrote `Collection.sort`, but the correct spelling is `Collections.sort`. What is the error you obtain with this method?

Comment: Then what should be the return type of method ??

Comment: Answer edited introducing code snippet and an hint on the type `Areas`.